# How to output vertical video in Handbrake 1.1.0?

Tags: resolution, video-conversion, handbrake

I have a vertical video recorded on an iPhone (one of the rare cases where it makes sense) that I am trying to convert to save storage space. The original is stored as 1920x1080, I assume with some flag saying it should be rotated.

Prior to updating, I had no problem converting similar videos using the `Fast 1080p 30` preset with the rotate filter, resulting in a smaller file with a resolution of 1080x1920. After updating to 1.1.0, I have been unable to output the video correctly. No matter what I change in the Dimensions tab, it locks the height to a max of 1080. Depending on the options, it may output either a 608x1080 video or a 1080x1080 pillarboxed video.

How can I output this video correctly? Or am I better off finding a way to revert to whatever version I had before?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the resolution is limited by the selected preset. You can create a new custom preset which allows higher resolutions.

Press *Presets* button for showing the side presets panel.

[image]

Then, click *Add* button.

[image]

And, finally, set the desired resolution:

[image]